# How to add an xml attribute after another specific attribute using T-SQL

Tags: xml, t-sql

I have xml

```
declare @xml xml = 
'<property>
<address addr="123 Main St" state="FL">
</address>
</property>'

set @xml.modify('insert attribute zip {"33312"} as last into (/property/address)[1]')

select @xml
```

I'm trying to put zip as the last attribute.  I know in XML it doesn't technically matter, but I do have lots of xml that would be much easier to read if I could arrange the attributes as I like.  It seems "as first" and "as last" have no effect.  How do I accomplish this?  Or at least put an attribute at the end?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

It really doesn't matter, but if you insist.

**SQL**

```
DECLARE @xml xml 
= N'<property>
    <address addr="123 Main St" state="FL">
    </address>
</property>';

SET @xml = @xml.query('<property>
<address>
{
    for $x in /property/address/@*
    return $x, attribute zip {"33312"}
}
</address>
</property>
');

--test
SELECT @xml;
```

**Output**

```
<property><address addr="123 Main St" state="FL" zip="33312" /></property>
```

Comment: thank you for the quick response.  I didn't want a select statement.  I'm looking to put an attribute after another attribute in the raw xml.  I look at a lot of raw xml and it would be much easier if the attributes were in a specific order.

Comment: Very close!  I should have given a more complete xml sample.  I have a large xml that has a Properties element with a bunch of Property nodes.  I'm trying to add an attribute to the end of the attributes.  Can the query return the whole xml with the added attribute?

Comment: Please update the question with the real XML. I will take a look.